# RestAssured Automation - Unable to find the exact jar file to import

Tags: rest-assured

I keep getting this compilation error :

> The method useRelaxedHTTPSValidation() is undefined for the type
>   RestAssured

when I use `RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();`

JARs used:

```
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
bsh-1.3.0.jar
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-exec-1.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4-sources.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
cssparser-0.9.16.jar
freemarker-2.3.14.jar
groovy-all-2.4.3.jar
guava-18.0.jar
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
htmlunit-2.12.jar
.htmlunit-2.17.jar
.htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar
.httpmime-4.4.1.jar
.jbehave-core-3.2.jar
.jbehave-core-3.6.8.jar
.jcommander-1.29.jar
.jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar
.jetty-util-7.0.0pre3.jar
.jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar
.jna-4.1.0.jar
.jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
.json-20090211.jar
.json-20151123.jar
.json-20160212.jar
.junit-4.11.jar
.jxl-2.6.12.jar
.jxl.jar
.log4j-1.2.17.jar
.nekohtml-1.9.22.jar
.netty-3.5.7.Final.jar
.phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar
.rest-assured-1.3.jar
.sac-1.3.jar
.selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.9.0.jar
.selenium-java-2.25.0 (1).jar
.selenium-java-2.25.0.jar
.selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
.selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
.selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar
.selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0 2.jar
.selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
.selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
.serializer-2.7.1.jar
.sikuli-api-1.1.0.jar
.sikulixapi-1.1.0.jar
.technbolts-jbehave-eclipse-plugin_1.0.7.jar
.testng-xslt-plugin-1.1.jar
.websocket-api-9.2.11.v20150529.jar
.websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529.jar
.websocket-common-9.1.1.v20140108.jar
.websocket-common-9.1.1.v20140108(1).jar
.xalan-2.7.1.jar
.xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
.xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
.xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
.rest-assured-2.9.0.jar
```

Please tell me what I am missing and why is it giving me this compilation error ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you re using `.rest-assured-1.3.jar`. I don't think that method exists in RestAssured 1.3: https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.3.1/com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html

Try upgrading to the latest version of RestAssured (currently 3.0.1).